# is there a way to use same variables in different functions without using global?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

```
check1 = False
def adding():
    global f_num, s_num, check1
    check1 = True
    e.delete(0, END)
    f_num = e.get()

    s_num = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)

def show_answer():
    if check1:
        e.insert(0,f_num+s_num)
```

I'm new to coding and using this website...I'm using tkinter module to build a calculator. when I set the `show_answer()` function in the *equal sign button* it was supposed to show the answer to the addition to the numbers.

Comment: You need to repeat your tutorial on functions, so that you learn to pass values into a function and return them properly.

Comment: well Idk hoow to do that

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me this basic language feature” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tkinter, then you can define it in your root. Like:

```
root.Variable = True
```

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.Check1 = 0

def command():
    print(root.Check1)
    root.Check1 += 1


Button(text="Hello World", command=command).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

It keeps adding 1 to `root.Check1` and you can access the variable normally inside and outside the functions. You can use this concept. Or stay with [`globals`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp) and use [`return`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_return.asp)